# How can I create a Barplot with 3 variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a problem to create an appropriate Barplot. Here is my data:

```
 Site Leaftype Bacteria_per_mm2           SD
1     A        E        1733540.8    455950.56
2     A        B        1062815.7    352876.56
3     A     MI_E        1414862.9    442902.69
4     A     MI_B         638189.9    287774.87
5     B        E              0.0         0.00
6     B        B              0.0         0.00
7     B     MI_E              0.0         0.00
8     B     MI_B         639858.4    213881.70
9     C        E        1862013.0    802574.16
10    C        B         628596.2    153344.48
11    C     MI_E        1417365.6    374644.06
12    C     MI_B         502209.6    270575.29
13    D        E              0.0         0.00
14    D        B         614831.3    176989.64
15    D     MI_E              0.0         0.00
16    D     MI_B       38271374.5 133237805.80
17    E        E        1084505.8    604725.59
18    E        B         306164.3    113604.13
19    E     MI_E         588135.8    178212.25
20    E     MI_B         294207.0    119656.46
21    F        E        1712406.8   1378365.84
22    F        B         329522.9    123385.05
23    F     MI_E              0.0         0.00
24    F     MI_B         389865.9    122340.59
25    G        E              0.0         0.00
26    G        B        6934997.3  28121464.95
27    G     MI_E         957702.0    235390.37
28    G     MI_B         373737.4    131594.27
29    H        E        1677647.0    609105.40
30    H        B         438390.6    145930.97
31    H     MI_E              0.0         0.00
32    H     MI_B         602317.8    187389.36
33    I        E        1683903.8    303170.48
34    I        B              0.0         0.00
35    I     MI_E              0.0         0.00
36    I     MI_B         407941.0    135698.56
37    K        E        1257192.5    297964.48
38    K        B         291982.3    124092.78
39    K     MI_E        1209432.5   1670628.39
40    K     MI_B         442144.7    182276.10
41    L        E        1453793.9    703390.84
42    L        B         663495.1    313438.15
43    L     MI_E        1405130.2  11237373.56
44    L     MI_B        2775709.1   9921931.93
45    N        E         461332.1    120115.39
46    N        B         760822.5    285298.68
47    N     MI_E        1647614.5    260567.19
48    N     MI_B         615109.4    171088.51
49    O        E         931423.6    498561.29
50    O        B         299768.5    144299.92
51    O     MI_E        1112035.5    285024.12
52    O     MI_B         335362.6    114015.88
53    P        E              0.0         0.00
54    P        B         501375.4     84989.70
55    P     MI_E              0.0         0.00
56    P     MI_B         869273.1    149036.53
57    Q        E         961873.2    189228.01
58    Q        B         381523.6    168520.10
59    Q     MI_E         894300.1    184394.29
60    Q     MI_B              0.0         0.00
61    R        E         966878.6    209821.35
62    R        B         284474.2     80791.71
63    R     MI_E         903893.8    558948.64
64    R     MI_B              0.0         0.00
65    S        E              0.0         0.00
66    S        B        1076163.4    927758.07
67    S     MI_E        1137479.7    305446.03
68    S     MI_B         802812.3    190456.51
69    T        E              0.0         0.00
70    T        B        2287681.5  10420861.06
71    T     MI_E              0.0         0.00
72    T     MI_B         761656.7    406262.84
```

I try to create a barplot, which shows me the number of Bacteria per mm2 leafsurface at the different `Sites` and for each `Leaftype`, so I want to create a barplot with one y (response) variable and 2 categorial variables. My first problem is, that `Leaftype` and `Sites` are not numeric and R is telling me, that it is not possible to create a barplot with variables, which are not a numeric vector.

Here is my code I used:

```
Bacteria_all<-read.delim("Mean_Bacteria_counts_final.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")# my data
Bacteria_all
str(Bacteria_all)
mean5<-Bacteria_all$Bacteria_per_mm2
mean5
sd5<-Bacteria_all$SD
sd5

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=Bacteria_all)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(x=Site,y=mean5),fill = "forestgreen")+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Site,ymin=mean5-sd5,ymax=mean5+sd5),width=0.5)+
  ylim(0,1000000)+
  labs(x='Sites and Tree Species',y= 'Bacterial number per mm2 leafsurface')
```

And here is the appropriate image, but `Leaftypes` are missing.

[image]

Can you please help me with this problem? I found some related questions, but I am not able to apply these answers to my problem, I am a beginner in R!

Hopefully, you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

How about adding `facet_wrap` to facet by `leaftype`:

```
ggplot(data=Bacteria_all)+
geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(x=Site,y=mean5),fill = "forestgreen")+
theme_bw()+
geom_errorbar(aes(x=Site,ymin=mean5-sd5,ymax=mean5+sd5),width=0.5)+
ylim(0,1000000)+
labs(x='Sites and Tree Species',y= 'Bacterial number per mm2 leafsurface') + 
facet_wrap( ~ Leaftype, ncol=2)
```

[image]

(Note: I only took a few rows of your data to make this.)

Another approach would be to dodge the bars by leaftype, but this would be more complex to do and would probably look less nice.